# Forzar el envío de información en row colapsada

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy trabajando con primefaces 6 y estoy utilizando el componente datatable con filas que son expandibles y colapsables debido a que puede tener n filas y no quisiera tenerlas abiertas todas tanto por performance como por que seria difícil de leer

Las filas representan fragmentos de un formulario que se va llenando de manera independiente y asíncrona, para que al final cuando yo tenga las n filas llenas, tenga que juntarlas en un todo y agregarle unas fechas y ese todo enviarlo, el problema viene aqui, ya que al enviar la información si las filas están colapsadas, la información dentro de la fila, en particular una lista, no es enviada a menos que la fila esté expandida, mi query desde JPA me trae la información correctamente ya que ahí hago un fetch de lo que quiero pero el tema es desde la vista, les comparto mi codigo

```
<p:form>
    <p:outputlabel value"Fecha de envio"/>
    <p:calendar value${registrarAccionDosBean.accionDos.fechaDeEnvio}/>
    <p:dataTable id="necesidades"
     value="#{registrarAccionDosBean.accionDos.necesidadesConTema}"
     rendered="#{not empty registrarAccionDosBean.accionDos.necesidadesConTema}"
     var="necesidad"
     rowKey="#{necesidad.idNecesidad}">
        <p:column style="width:16px">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion>
            <h:panelGroup id="grupoTema">
                <h:panelGroup id="edicion" rendered="#{necesidad.tema.idTema ne  null}">
                  <p:row>
                    <p:column >
                       <h:outputLabel value="#{etiq.lbl_comunes_requerido} #{etiq.etiqueta_checkbox_transparenciasFocalizadas}" styleClass="textoAcciones"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column >
                        <!-- Tabla con el problema -->
                        <p:dataTable id="transparenciasInplace"
                     var="transparencias" 
                     value="#{registrarAccionDosBean.transparenciasFocalizadas}"
                     selection="#{necesidad.tema.transparenciasFocalizadas}"
                     rowKey="#{transparencias.idTf}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Objetivos
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{transparencias.descripcion}" styleClass="textoAccionesSmall"/>        
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                     </p:column>
                  </p:row>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:form>
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de enviar la información, he intentado "despertar" el lazy loading imprimiendo el tamaño del arreglo que está en la lista pero no pasa nada

Imagen Formulario colapsado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de formulario dentro de cada row

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen lleno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El boton que esta junto a la fecha es el que manda a guardar todo el formulario, adicional cada fila tiene su propio botón guardar dentro para guardar de manera individual cada fragmento anidado en dicha fila

La lista "objetivos" es la que no se envia

Comment: ¿El DataTable interno tiene otros datos que no tienen relación con el DataTable externo?

Comment: @Garrizano edite mi pregunta para poner en contexto lo que me mencionas, la tabla exterior representa información que cree en otro caso de uso, la tabla interior es el caso de uso que estoy actualmente y solo comparten los ids, una vez que estén llenos estos debo llenar el campo "Fecha de envio" y mandar todo el formulario a persistir

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar una imagen del formulario?

Comment: @Garrizano edite mi pregunta colocando unas imágenes

Comment: Prueba guardando la lista de transparenciasFocalizadas en una variable List en el objeto registrarAccionDosBean. Si así funciona es cuestión de adaptar el código, pero primero comprueba eso.

Comment: ¿La acción de guardar cada información de cada fila y guardar todas las filas lo realizas en un mismo tiempo o se lleva tiempo en rellenar cada fila y guardarlo todo?

Comment: @Garrizano Se guardan en diferentes tiempos, haz de cuenta que voy al revés , primero guardo los hijos, que en este caso son cada fila y al final guardo el padre que sería la fecha + las filas y en ese momento asigno a cada fila la referencia del objeto padre, lo hago de esta manera ya que el todo debe de ser calificado como tal por medio de la fecha que pongo, y cada usuario llena a como pueda la información de cada fila

Comment: ¿Tu entidad padre posee relación directa con la entidad hija? ¿Hay alguna relación en cascada de padre a hijo? ¿Cómo es tu método de guardado del padre?

Comment: @Garrizano Estan relacionados de la siguiente manera, AccionDos(padre) tiene uno o muchos Temas, a su vez Tema es padre de objetivos los cuales tambien puede tener uno o muchos, esta anidacion es la del problema, todas son bidireccionales, para guardar tengo que convertir de DTO a Entidad es aqui donde veo que la lista objetivos viene null si no expando las filas

Comment: Prueba añadiendo esto a tu tabla:

     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.pruebaDeEvento}" </p:ajax>

En pruebaDeEvento haz un simple System.out.println con alguna frase cualquiera. Prueba ir seleccionando las columnas y si el evento no se ejecuta probablemente haya algún detalle con tus componentes y es por eso que al ejecutar la acción del botón Guardar los datos no se están enviando.